# Applying percent change based on unique identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm calculating margins from a sales table in SQL and I need to reduce sales amounts if there is a discount in a sale based on it's invoice number. For this sample a 25% discount is applied Invoice 123. The total sales amount for invoice 123 is $100.00 but there is a 25% discount applied to that amount. What I want to do is apply that 25% discount to all sales numbers for invoice 123 so I can get the actual revenue number.

Sample Data:

```
ID            Type              ProductType       Amount
123           Sale               Jeans            50.00  
123           Sale               T-Shirt          30.00  
123           Sale               Sock             20.00   
123           Discount - 25%     NULL            -25.00

456           Sale               Jeans            60.00  
456           Sale               T-Shirt          40.00  
456           Sale               Sock             70.00
```

Expected Result:

```
ID            Type            ProductType       Amount      Actual Amount
123           Sale               Jeans            50.00          41.67
123           Sale               T-Shirt          30.00          21.67
123           Sale               Sock             20.00          11.67
123           Discount - 25%     NULL            -25.00          0.00

456           Sale               Jeans            60.00          60.00
456           Sale               T-Shirt          40.00          40.00
456           Sale               Sock             70.00          70.00
```

I've tried creating a new column where I multiple the amount times the discount rate but I can't get the numbers correct because it needs to be applied to the invoice number each discount corresponds to. 
I'd like to have a new column that shows the adjusted amount based on the discount rate and then the discount amount showing zero.

Comment: How do you know the amount of the discount?  Is it always 25%?  What if there is more than one discount?

Comment: In the type column it will specify the amount so I am able to parse through and extract the discount rate. In our accounting system it only allows one discount per invoice so there is only 1 discount per unique invoice number.

Comment: How does 25% discount on 50 generates a result of 41.67? Also, how does 25% discount on 20.00 generates 11.67? Please explain the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use window functions to calculate the sum of the negative values for an `id` divided by the number of non negative values for that `id` by `CASE` expressions as arguments to the functions. The result of the division can than be deducted from the price. Additionally use a `CASE` to get zero for the negative values.

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.amount,
       CASE 
         WHEN t1.amount <= 0 THEN
           0
         ELSE t1.amount
              + sum(CASE
                      WHEN t1.amount < 0 THEN
                        t1.amount
                      ELSE
                        0
                    END) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id)
              /
              count(CASE
                      WHEN t1.amount >= 0 THEN
                        1
                    END)  OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id)
       END actual_amount
       FROM elbat t1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=72fcf2670031432787a7b7ab452f2d87)